# as when choosing a number, increase the number of items?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display the number of 'inputs' that is selected in 'select'. The task is to display the "input" after selecting the value in the "select".
How to correctly implement the idea. Maybe it's better to use another way?

Right now I have just a line displayed:
`<Input placeholder = "TEST TEST TEST" /> <Input placeholder = "TEST TEST TEST" />`

```
class Test extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tableAmountColumns: '',
            test: ``
        }
    }

    handleChange(value) {
        this.setState({tableAmountColumns: value});

        const {tableAmountColumns, test} = this.state;

        let tests = ``;
        let i;
        for (i = 0; i < tableAmountColumns; i++) {
            tests += `<Input placeholder="TEST TEST TEST"/>`;
        }
        this.setState({test: tests});

    }
    render() {
        const {test} = this.state;
        const dataTableRules =
            <div>
                <Input placeholder="enter title rule"/>
                <Select defaultValue="0" style={{width: 220}} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
                    <Option value="1">1</Option>
                    <Option value="2">2</Option>                   
                </Select>
            </div>;


        return (
            <div className="rules">
             {test}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: You should start by passing the value/event to handleChange.

Comment: can i see an example?

Comment: Bind the function is your constructor instead (best practice) and then you can write `onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)`

Comment: I do not fully understand what I should do